# Attask- how to know that whether particular custom form is selected in the task or not

Tags: categories, attask

I want to search only those task from the project, which has a particular custom form (though not selected any field).

```
attask/api/task/5775...?fields=parameterValues,category
```

This returns only first custom form(category) object selected in the task and not all the custom forms..

I want to find all those task which contains particular categoryID..

```
Attask/api/ task/search?categoryID= 46785335&fields=parameterValues
```

It doesn't return me response when custom form selected after another custom form..

Answer (score 0):

Since multiple custom forms is a new feature it is still only in earlyAccess this has not been released to the current API. You can however do this using the unsupported API.

the following will do what you are wanting.

```
GET attask/api-unsupported/task/search?objectCategoriesMM:ID=55a4232e005dc2668af39a4f24a4db40
```

This will search all forms not just the primary(first) form